# is it possible to use other private repositories (bitbucket,github,gitlab) instead of one provided by Azure API manager?

Tags: git, azure, azure-api-management

**Problem statement** 
we are currently having Azure API manager for each environment (dev,test,uat,stage, prod). synching all of these internal git repositories from azure is difficult. is it possible for us to use external private repo instead of using one provided by the Azure API manager?

Answer (score 1):

APIM can't talk to you external repo directly, but you could have one external centralized repo and local environment with multiple upstreams. So when you need to pull configuration from APIM you can do so into local environment and then push to your external repo. Pushing changes will be the reverse - pull from external into local environment, push to APIM.